# System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext stores UserName and Password as plain-text in memory

Tags: c#, security, .net-4.0, principalcontext

If you use the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext constructor that takes a user name and password, that user name and (more disconcertingly) password are held internally as plain text strings in the object.

Is there a way around this obvious security risk?

Comment: Where do you got this information from?

Comment: From debugging the PrincipalContext. If you drill down into the object in the debugger, you can see the user name and password as plain text.